# jquery small issue I need help with

Tags: jquery

Hi I need help with a bit of jquery, I am renaming dropdown lists when a checkbox next to them is clicked. I want to get the selected option value of the dropdown called 'Prev' in the code below and assign to the checkbox that is clicked. I hope it makes sense. Thanks

```
$('.mutuallyexclusive').live("click", function() {


            checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
            $('.mutuallyexclusive:checked').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
                $(this).attr('name', 'chk');
            });
            $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);

            if (checkedState) {
                jQuery('#myForm select[name=cat.parent_id]').attr('name', 'bar')

                // here is the bit i need help with
                // get the selected option of the dropdown prev and set it to $(this).val.. something along those lines
                var prev = $(this).prev('select').attr("name", 'cat.parent_id');

            }
            else {
                var prev = $(this).prev('select').attr("name", 'dd');
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML markup of the form items you're working with?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do. To get the value of a selected option $("select option:selected").val();

Comment: yes, from the select list 'var Prev' and set the value  to the checkbox that was checked

Comment: To get the selected value of a <select> element, you simply need to do $("select").val(), with the appropriate element ID or whatever as the CSS selector. It has the same effect as $("select option:selected").val() as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML structure would help a ton, but the first optimization is to cache your initial checkbox.  Next, take advantage of implied iteration in jQuery.  If I understand what you're attempting to do I end up with this:

```
$('.mutuallyexclusive').live("click", function() {

    var $check = $(this);

    var checkedState = $check.attr('checked');

    $('.mutuallyexclusive:checked')
      .attr('checked', '')
      .attr('name', 'chk');

    $check.attr('checked', checkedState);

    if (checkedState) {
        $check.attr('name', $check.prev('select').val());
    } else {
        $check.attr('name', 'dd');
    }

});
```

I couldn't tell for sure from your question whether you wanted to assign the value of the checkbox to the select list, or vice versa.  I went with "set the name of the checkbox to the value of the select list".  Hopefully that's what you were after.